# Rails 3 How to access user data from user_id column in belongs_to :user association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am trying to create an activity feed with the most recent activities from my TrainingSession model.

```
class User
  has_many :training_sessions
end

class TrainingSession
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The problem is that I am trying to access a user's data in the view page (mainly the user's name) by instantiating an object from the TrainingSessions database table, as shown below:

```
<% @training_sessions.each do |training_session| %>
<%= training_session.user_id %>
```

The problem is that, although I successfully get the user's id, I cannot call, for example:

```
training_session.user_id.name
```

... otherwise I get the NoMethodError shown below:

```
undefined method `first_name' for 2:Fixnum
```

so my question is ... how can I access the user's data from the TrainingSession's object?

any help would be much appreciated. Pretty stumped on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you get a "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"-error is that some training sessions do not belong to a user. The solution is to cleanup your database:

```
DELETE FROM training_sessions WHERE user_id IS NULL
```

If it is expected behavior to have training sessions that don't belong to a user, you have to check that the user is not `nil` in your loop:

```
<% @training_sessions.each do |training_session| %>
  <% unless training_session.user.nil? %>
    <%= training_session.user.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. Yeah I needed to check that the user is not nil, as it is expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to rename your model name (`TreningSessions`) into singular name (`TreningSession`). That's the convention rails uses. Rename only model, leave `has_many` without change.

Now the user association,you should call it via `user` object. `user_id` is just a attribute that represents field in database and it's value, while `user` is an association object. Try this:

`training_session.user.name`

[More on ActiveRecord relations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried that but then I get this error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass. I'm assuming this mean it can't find the user? I think it's important that this is not a traditional view page with the user's id in the url. I am displaying this on my home page so I'm not sure rails has a way to access the user?

Comment: Sorry that was actually a typo. Your solution still doesn't work for me though, and I think it might be because the user_id is not being passed in by the url in my application, as the activity feed is on my homepage. I have come up with a solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing, creating a local user variable containing the user_id and using that variable with the find method on the user model to instantiate an instance variable @training_session_user in my controller, like the following:

```
@training_sessions.each do |training_session|
  user = training_session.user_id
  @training_session_user = User.find(user)
end
```

then I call this in my view:

```
@training_session_user.first_name
```

and it retrieves the name with no errors.

If anyone has a better solution please feel free, but I will mark this as correct for now.

Comment: This is a very bad way to do it. You should just be able to do `training_session.user.name`. If you get errors it means some training sessions don't belong to a user. See my answer below.